# Exchange Web Services: More Complex SearchFilters

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

In a previous project where I used EWS, my search criteria was much simpler: find emails with "xxx" in the Subject.

I'm now building this code into a more multi-purpose application; I will be monitoring various mailboxes for various criteria, for example:

`Find all mail items where the recipient is "email@example.com", AND subject contains "xxx" AND (body contains "yyy" OR body contains "zzz")`

However, using a SearchFilterCollection, although I can add multiple SearchFilters, I don't see how to apply different logical operators... there seems to be one logical operator per SearchFilterCollection:

`SearchFilterCollection sfc = new SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or,                        new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, "Test"));`

I suppose one solution would be to find a superset of the desired mail items, and then filter them more accurately later, when they are being processed. But I was wondering if there is a better way of filtering at the start, using SearchFilters or any other means?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/akashb/archive/2010/03/05/how-to-build-a-complex-search-using-searchfilter-and-searchfiltercollection-in-ews-managed-api-1-0.aspx

Comment: @Bolu - looking promising - you should post this as an answer....

Comment: [HOW TO: Build a complex search using SearchFilter and SearchFilterCollection in EWS Managed API 1.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/akashb/archive/2010/03/05/how-to-build-a-complex-search-using-searchfilter-and-searchfiltercollection-in-ews-managed-api-1-0.aspx)

Comment: lol - better, but this is still a comment. I can't still accept it as an answer. ;)

Comment: My answer was deleted&converted by someone to the comment above. whatever, I'm fine as long as you know how to do it now.

Comment: Off topic: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121100/answer-suggested-by-op-get-removed/121101#comment320660_121101

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could build-up your complex Searchfilter using `SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection (LogicalOperator, SearchFilter[])`

Check: [HOW TO: Build a complex search using SearchFilter and SearchFilterCollection in EWS Managed API 1.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/akashb/archive/2010/03/05/how-to-build-a-complex-search-using-searchfilter-and-searchfiltercollection-in-ews-managed-api-1-0.aspx)